# No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI when POSTing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, http-post, crud

I am trying to build a movie rental app using asp.net for backend and EXT JS for front end.
So far, I am able to access the data using this code for the controller:

```
[AllowCrossSite]
[HttpGet]
// api/movie/Get - link to access the data on the browser.
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    using (VidlyDBContext dbContext = new VidlyDBContext())
    {
        movies = dbContext.Movies.ToList();
        if (movies.Count == 0)
        {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "No data found.");
        }
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, movies);
    }
}
```

But whenever I try to do a POST, this error appears:
`No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://localhost:44321/api/movie/Create'.`

This is the code for my controller:

```
[AllowCrossSite]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Create(string MovieName, string Director, string Genre, string Description, decimal RentalCost, string Picture)
    {
    using (VidlyDBContext dbContext = new VidlyDBContext())
    {
        Movie createMovie = new Movie();
        if (createMovie != null)
        {
            createMovie.MovieName = MovieName;
            createMovie.Director = Director;
            createMovie.Genre = Genre;
            createMovie.Description = Description;
            createMovie.RentalCost = RentalCost;
            createMovie.Picture = Picture;

            dbContext.Movies.Add(createMovie);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, createMovie);
        }
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Please provide the correct information.");
    }
}
```

My RouteConfig looks like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

I think the routing is really my problem but I can't seem to figure out why. If I can use api/movie/Get to access the data, why can't I use api/movie/Create when posting?

I researched everything I can on google and stackoverflow before posting this question, maybe I'm just dumb and I'm just applying the solution incorrectly but I'm just really confused at this routing thing.

I have tried inserting [FromUri] into the parameters for Create ex: Create([FromUri]string MovieName ...) but it didn't seem to work.

I also tried adding [Route("api/movie/Create")] on the top of the create method, but it also didn't work. (Maybe the syntax was incorrect? I'm really not sure)

I also made different methods like Update and Delete and applied those ideas above, but I still got the same result.

Comment: Your create method takes in arguments.  So your route would be `https://localhost:44321/api/movie/Create/{MovieName}/...` with all the other params. I would consider passing json via the body with all that data in it instead.

Comment: As @FelixCastor indicated, try passing in a complex object as a parameter([FromBody] NewMovieObject) into your Create method.

Comment: That worked! I changed the parameters to: (`public HttpResponseMessage Create([FromBody] Movie movie)`). Thank you!
Can you post this as an answer so I can flag it as one? I can't seem to do it when it's a comment.